# Extracting lower and upper bounds of an inequality solution from Reduce/Solve

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I am solving a set of inequalities and 1 equation

```
val[fa_] := 0.11/(0.3 8.7 2.4 10^-3 (fa/10^12)^(3/2))

fa = 8/10 10^14;
Reduce[Rf^2/Sqrt[Rm] == val[fa] && 1 > Rf > (fa/10^19)^(1/3) && Rf^(4/3) (fa/10^19)^(2/9) > Rm > (fa/10^19)^(2/3), {Rf, Rm}]
```

which gives an output such as

```
0.0221548 < Rf < 0.0233178 && Rm == 1660.31 Rf^4
```

when I use Reduce. (An equivalent conditional expression if I use Solve).
How can I automatically extract the lower and upper bounds on Rf and the corresponding Rm? (Ultimately I need to loop over the fa variable...)

Answer (score 3):

Does [`Minimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize)/[`Maximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize) suffice?

```
Minimize[{Rf, 0.0221548 < Rf < 0.0233178 && Rm == 1660.31 Rf^4}, {Rf, Rm}]
Maximize[{Rf, 0.0221548 < Rf < 0.0233178 && Rm == 1660.31 Rf^4}, {Rf, Rm}]
```

> {0.0221548, {Rf -> 0.0221548, Rm -> 0.000399993}}

> {0.0233178, {Rf -> 0.0233178, Rm -> 0.000490833}}

Answer (score 2):

> How can I automatically extract the lower and upper bounds on Rf and
> the corresponding Rm?

For lower/upper bounds, the easiest way might be to enumerate all possible cases, something like (made up)

```
ClearAll[Rf,any1,any2];
expr = 0.0221548 < Rf <= 0.0233178 && 1 < Rf < 2 && Rm == 1660.31 Rf^4
```

Then use `Cases` with `Alternatives` to pick all 4 possible cases of combinations of `<` and `<=`

```
Cases[expr, (any1_ < Rf < any2_ | any1_ < Rf <= any2_ | 
    any1_ <= Rf < any2_ | any1_ <= Rf <= any2_) :> {any1, any2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to account for `>` and `>=` combination, you do the same, but reverse the lower and upper in the final result. So you would do both checks in order to make sure you picked all 8 cases.

To select the term with `Rm` only, one way is to use `Select`

```
Select[expr, 
 MemberQ[DeleteDuplicates@Cases[#, _Symbol, Infinity], Rm] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]